# SOA FTP Adapter, Error in listing files in the remote directory

Tags: ftp, soa, jdeveloper, oracle-soa

I'm getting following error for file transfer using SOA FTP Adapter.

BINDING.JCA-11430
Error in listing files in the remote directory.
Error in listing files in the remote directory.
Unable to list file in remote directory.
Please make sure that the ftp server settings are correct.

```
  at oracle.tip.adapter.ftp.FTPAgent.getFileList(FTPAgent.java:419).....
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

i also have faced similar issue with FTP file adapter.To use file adapter is soa you need to do two things mainly

1. set the ftp adapter component in your process or SOA application
2. List item setup the FTP adapter setting from the weblogic console.

here, weblogic console is for the domain created while installation on SOA Suite.
you can open console by "https://HOST-NAME:7001/console".
port number can be different according to your setup.

to setup the FTP Adapter from console here is the link goto step 11 directly.[LINK](http://logicoy.com/blogs/oracle-soa-file-ftp-adapter/)

Comment: is there a way to sftp a zip file in OSB ?

Answer (score 0):

according to Oracle Support note 467720.1:

The problem is caused by the list command (ls) command executed by the FTP adapter returning an FTP error code of 550 (Requested action not taken:  file unavailable).  This error code will cause the adapter to be shut down, failing the FTP adapter operation.

This can be overcome by following these steps:

(1)  File name patterns should be provided in the FTP adapter wizard field "Include Files with Name Pattern", for example such as can*.txt, i.e. it needs to have some characters and then * in the pattern, this solution will not work if providing only * as the file name pattern.

(2)  A file with a different pattern that does not match with the pattern provided above should always be present in the input ftp directory.  Such as a file called test.txt is put into the ftp directory and the BPEL/ESB process file pattern name in "Include Files with Name Pattern" is can*.txt, as in (1) above.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to SFTP zip file in OSB